# Output recaptcha through js.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I need to display content in a lightbox along with recaptcha.This was very easy except that recaptcha can be used only one per page.So, that threw the hidden div option away. Now, iam trying to render the content via js.erb using jquery's html() method. Rest of the content is rendered correctly.But, i'm having trouble rendering recaptcha.Is there a way to render recaptcha via jQuery html() method? I am using Ambethia reCaptcha.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I used a single Div(main lightbox container).Within that div, i added another div which wrapped <%=recaptcha_tags%>.This inner div was placed using absolute positioning.For the rest of the content, i used jquery's append() function instead of html() function.